# how to use useTransition for resizable columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to resize the table columns and I use react-resizable library to change the resizable This is what I did:

```
const ResizableHeaderCell = ({ width, onResize, rtl, col, ...restProps }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const handleResize = (e, { size }) => {
    onResize(size.width);
  };

  return (
    <Resizable
      width={width}
      height={0}
      onResize={handleResize}
      dir={!rtl ? "rtl" : "ltr"}
      resizeHandles={["w"]}
      handle={
        <span
          className={clsx("react-resizable-handle", classes.resizableHandle)}
          style={{
            transform: rtl ? "scaleX(-1)" : undefined,
            top: "4px",
            left: col.left ? col.left : 0,
            backgroundImage: "none",
          }}
        />
      }
    >
      <TableCell align={col.align ?? "center"} key={col.field}>
        <TableSortLabel
          active={restProps.active}
          direction={restProps.direction}
          onClick={restProps.onClick}
          hideSortIcon={restProps.hideSortIcon}
          key={col.field}
        >
          <TableCell
            {...restProps}
            key={col.field}
            align={col.align ?? "center"}
            style={{
              width: width,
              paddingRight: "0px",
              borderBottom: "none",
              textAlign: "center",
            }}
          >
            {restProps.title}
          </TableCell>
        </TableSortLabel>
      </TableCell>
    </Resizable>
  );
};

export default ResizableHeaderCell;
```

And I used it in the table:

```
 const handleResize = (index) => (size) => {
    setColumnWidths((prevColumnWidths) => {
      const newColumnWidths = [...prevColumnWidths];
      newColumnWidths[index] = size;
      return newColumnWidths;
    });
  };


  <TableHead className={props.tableHeadClassName}>
          <TableRow className={props.tableRowClassName}>
            {ColumnsData.map((col, index) => {
              return (
                !col.hide &&
                  <ResizbleHeaderCell
                    width={columnWidths[index]}
                    onResize={handleResize(index)}
                    rtl={true}
                    col={col}
                    active={sortBy === col.field}
                    direction={col.field === sortBy ? sortOrderByLetter : "asc"}
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      e.stopPropagation();
                      col.sort && onSort(col.field);
                    }}
                    hideSortIcon={!col.sort}
                    classes={{ root: classes.sortLabel }}
                    title={col.title}
                  ></ResizbleHeaderCell>
              
              );
            })}
          </TableHead >
          </TableRow >
```

Everything is fine, but when resizing happens, a lag occurs.It seems that the `setState` is happening a lot. How can I limit it to `setState` when the MouseDown ?Can anyone tell me where my problem is?